# Python3.6 add audio to cv2 processed video

Tags: python-3.x, audio, video-processing, opencv, python

I have a code that takes in a video then constructs a list of frames from that video. then does something with each frame then put the frames back together into cv2 video writer. However, when the video is constructed again, it loses all its audio.

Comment: The OpenCV VideoWriter does not encode audio. Use another tool, like FFMPEG to combine an audio track with your video file.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into it!

Answer (score 3):

Stephen Meschke is right ! Use FFMPEG to extract and import audio.
Type in cmd:

## Extract audio:

`ffmpeg -i yourvideo.avi -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn sound.mp3`

## Import audio:

`ffmpeg -i yourvideo.avi -i sound.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.avi`